# multiprocessing gives wrong number of outputs, repeats outside scope

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocess

When I use multiprocessing.pool.starmap it repeats the process outside the part I define as the process. 
I am confused as to why.

MRA:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def countAdd( first, second, third ): 
    added = str( first + second + third ) 
    with open( "test.txt", 'a' ) as f: 
        f.write( "this is string: " + added + '\n')

testlist = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ]

testlist2 = [  7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 ]

testlist3 = [ 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18  ]

arglist = [ (testlist[ test ], testlist2[ test ], testlist3[ test ]) for test in range( 0, len( testlist ) )  ]

print( arglist )
print( len( testlist ) )

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    with Pool( 3 ) as pool: 
        pool.starmap( countAdd, arglist )
```

Output:

```
[(1, 7, 13), (2, 8, 14), (3, 9, 15), (4, 10, 16), (5, 11, 17), (6, 12, 18)]
6
[(1, 7, 13), (2, 8, 14), (3, 9, 15), (4, 10, 16), (5, 11, 17), (6, 12, 18)]
6
[(1, 7, 13), (2, 8, 14), (3, 9, 15), (4, 10, 16), (5, 11, 17), (6, 12, 18)]
6
[(1, 7, 13), (2, 8, 14), (3, 9, 15), (4, 10, 16), (5, 11, 17), (6, 12, 18)]
6
```

file:

```
this is string: 21
this is string: 24
this is string: 27
this is string: 33
this is string: 36
```

So I'm really confused. Why are the print statements also printed repeatedly? But only 4 times?!
Why does the file only contain 5 times the output of the function and not 6 times, eventhough the `arglist` contains 6 tuples?

I searched around, found a similar probleme but isn't it.
[Python Multiprocessing data output wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40099585/python-multiprocessing-data-output-wrong)

Thanks for taking the time to respond.

EDIT: 
Based on the comments by MisterMiyagi I changed my code to the following, but there are still problems:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool


def countAdd( first, second, third ): 
    added = str( first + second + third ) 
    with open( "test.txt", 'a' ) as f: 
        f.write( "this is string: " + added + '\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':  

    testlist = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ]

    testlist2 = [  7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 ]

    testlist3 = [ 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18  ]

    arglist = [ (testlist[ test ], testlist2[ test ], testlist3[ test ]) for test in range( 0, len( testlist ) )  ]

    print( arglist )
    print( len( arglist ) )

    with Pool( 3 ) as pool: 
        pool.starmap( countAdd, arglist )


    print( "done")
```

I repeatedly ran the code. Sometimes I get the six lines of output but othertimes I don't. I ran the code 10 times and I got 54 lines of text in the output file. What is going on here?

Comment: Did you write this code yourself? Do you know why you need ``if __name__ == '__main__': ``? That one answers your first question.

Comment: With the code given, I cannot reproduce your problem. The ``test.txt`` contains all 6 outputs for me.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi really? That is weird. I'll investigate further. Thank you pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I think I found why I didn't get the right output. Might it be that while one process is appending, another can't? I have run it multiple times now and sometimes I do get six lines and othertimes less than that.